# Reconnecting to Bluetooth in android / Reading after Reconnect

Tags: java, android

I have a program that establishes a Bluetooth connection, reads the InputStream to a textView, and can disconnect from the module. While I can successfully disconnect and reconnect to the module (HC-05) as many times as I please, I can't get an InputStream read anymore after I reconnect. I believe it is because I don't know how to reinitialize the thread I'm using to read the InputStream. I am very new to java and android programming, any help with this issue would be appreciated.This is my code:

The textView for the read display is called 'Status' and I am hoping to "reset" the thread upon the onclick connect().

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable {
private BluetoothAdapter adapter;
private InputStream inputStream;
private OutputStream outputStream;
private Thread thread;
private TextView Status;
private TextView Connection;
private BluetoothSocket socket = null;
private boolean threadStatusInitial=true;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Status=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.StatusID);

    Connection=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ConnectionStatus);

    adapter= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if(adapter==null){

        Toast.makeText(this,"bluetooth is unavailable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        finish();
        return;
    }
    thread=new Thread(this);

}

public void connect(View view){
    Set<BluetoothDevice> devices=adapter.getBondedDevices();


    for(BluetoothDevice device:devices){
        if(device.getName().startsWith("HC-05")){
            try {
                socket=device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device.getUuids()[0].getUuid());

                socket.connect();

                Connection.setText("Connected");

                inputStream=socket.getInputStream();

                outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();


                if (threadStatusInitial){
                   thread.start();
                   threadStatusInitial=false; //this ensures that the thread.start() method will only be called during the first connection
               }





            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Can't Connect",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        }
    }


}

public void Disconnect(View view) throws InterruptedException {
    if (inputStream != null) {
        try {inputStream.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
        inputStream = null;
    }

    if (outputStream != null) {
        try {outputStream.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
        outputStream = null;
    }

    if (socket != null) {
        try {socket.close();} catch (Exception e) {Toast.makeText(this,"Can't Connect",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        socket = null;
    }

    Connection.setText("Disconnected");
}

@Override
public void run() {
String textInput = "hi";
byte[] writeBytes=textInput.getBytes();
if(outputStream!=null){
    try {
        outputStream.write(writeBytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Unable to Write to Bluetooth ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


    while(inputStream!=null){

        byte [] buffer=new byte[2048];
        try {
            int length=inputStream.read(buffer);
            final String strReceived = new String(buffer, 0, length);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Status.setText(strReceived);
                }});

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }
}
```

}

Comment: yes if you don't call the start() method after a reconnect then the run() will not be called. try creating a new thread() on every reconnection? or try using AsyncTask class

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would it be possible to create a new thread() on every re-connection for the same run() method? The current thread I'm using is initialized outside of my program methods but within a runnable() "parent" method. Is it possible to start a new thread within the connect() method that implements the run() method? Sorry if my questions are a bit basic.

Comment: for example: 

    new Thread() {
                                public void run() {
                                      //your connection code
                                    }
                                }
                            }.start();